# File incorrectly reading

Tags: c#, macos, encoding

I am working on a text compressor application however I'm having an issue reading a file. Upon getting the byte[] of the file I encode it in ASCII (used in the .txt file I'm testing) then print the string to the screen. The results I'm getting are incomplete, with very few characters showing and the text of the document not readable. I have been able to open the file in text editors successfully so I've concluded it is not corrupted. I hope this question helps other as well. My relevant code and a snippet of the results are below.

Code:

```
//Takes the file and breaks it down into a byte array
public void ReadFile(string fileLocation) { 
    FileStream file = new FileStream(@fileLocation, FileMode.Open);         //Opens the file 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length];                                  //Sets the Length of the array 'buffer' to the length of the amound of bytes in the file
    file.Read(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length);                                 //Reads the data (bytes) from the file and stores it in 'buffer'
    file.Close();                                                           //Closes the file

    Convert(buffer);                                                        //Starts the function 'Convert' passing in 'buffer' as the dada value
}

//Takes the byte array and puts it into ASCII encoding
public void Convert(byte[] byteData) {
    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteData);                  //Convert and store the converted data into the variable 'data'
}
```

Results Snippet:

[image]

The area in the results consisting of '(??' is where the text in the file should be shown.

Comment: Is there a reason to do that to read a text file ? What about StreamReaders ?

Comment: I've tried using StreamReader as well with the same result

Comment: If you open your file with notepad, what do you see ?

Comment: It displays the names of star systems, as it should

Comment: that's not an ASCII file

Comment: that's a word document

Comment: It is a word document, however it claims it 'uses the ASCII Extended Character Set'

Comment: doesn't matter what it it claims, as you can see